# How is the implementation of LinkedHashMap different from HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, complexity-theory, linkedhashmap

If LinkedHashMap's time complexity is same as HashMap's complexity why do we need HashMap? What are all the extra overhead LinkedHashMap has when compared to HashMap in Java?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

LinkedHashMap will take more memory. Each entry in a normal `HashMap` just has the key and the value. Each `LinkedHashMap` entry has those references *and* references to the next and previous entries. There's also a little bit more housekeeping to do, although that's usually irrelevant.

Comment: As a result, the performance is slightly lower compared to that of HashMap.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Is it like values in case of LinkedHashMap consist of extra references to previous and next value, deletion or insertion of any item would take extra cost for reconnecting as well? It would be great if I get complete implementation either has a link or explained.

Comment: @Passionate programmer: The source code is publicly available - why not look there? And yes, insertion and deletion does require the linked list to be updated.

Comment: @I am not a Java programmer and I don't know where it can be found :(.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks for helping out, I don't think I have the source code in that URL, should I log in??

Comment: @Passionate programmer If you've already downloaded a JDK the sources are included in JAVA_HOME\src.zip

Comment: @Passionateprogrammer - one way to find Java sourcecode is to Google it; e.g. look for "java.util.HashMap.java.html" and you'll get hits for various versions.

Comment: @StinePike: Well there's a difference in terms of *behaviour* - but in terms of time spent to look up, add items etc they're broadly equivalent. (In terms of complexity - the constant factors are probably slightly different.)

Comment: As noted below, LinkedHashMap is more efficient when iterating.  This impacts resizing a little.  Plus if you're passing a map with an expectation that the consumer wants to look at every node, this might be a better choice.  Generally, though, puts/removes will be slightly slower due to small overhead.

Answer (score 33):

> If LinkedHashMap's time complexity is same as HashMap's complexity why do we need HashMap?

You should not confuse complexity with performance.  Two algorithms can have the same complexity, yet one can consistently perform better than the other.

Remember that `f(N) is O(N)` means that:

```
limit(f(N), N -> infinity) <= C*N
```

where `C` is a constant.  The complexity says nothing about how small or large the `C` values are.  For two different algorithms, the constant `C` will most likely be *different*.

(And remember that big-O complexity is about the behavior / performance as `N` gets very large.  It tells you nothing about the behavior / performance for smaller `N` values.)

---

Having said that:

- The difference in performance between `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` operations in equivalent use-cases is relatively small.
- A `LinkedHashMap` uses more memory.  For example, the Java 11 implementation has two additional reference fields in each map entry to represent the before/after list.  On a 64 bit platform without compressed OOPs the extra overhead is 16 bytes per entry.
- Relatively small differences in performance and/or memory usage can actually matter a lot to people with performance or memory critical applications<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - ... and also to people who obsess about these things unnecessarily.</sup>

Answer (score 16):

- LinkedHashMap additionally maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries, that will provide a reproducable order. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).
- HashMap doesn't have these extra costs (runtime,space) and should prefered over LinkedHashMap when you don't care about insertion order.

Comment: I think you mean iteration order?

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff You are right, but answer is usually correct because `iteration order = insertion order` by deafult. Possible alternative to *insertion order* is an *access-order*.

Answer (score 10):

LinkedHashMap is a useful data structure when you need to know the insertion order of keys to the Map. One suitable use case is for the implementation of an LRU cache. Due to order maintenance of the LinkedHashMap, the data structure needs additional memory compared to HashMap. In case insertion order is not a requirement, you should always go for the HashMap.

Answer (score 8):

There is another major difference between HashMap and LinkedHashMap :**Iteration is more efficient in case of LinkedHashMap.**

As Elements in **LinkedHashMap** are connected with each other so iteration requires time proportional to the size of the map, regardless of its capacity. 
But in case of **HashMap**; as there is no fixed order, so iteration over it requires time proportional to its capacity.

I have put more details on my [blog](http://geekrai.blogspot.in/2013/06/linkedhashmap-implementation-in-java.html).

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` does not maintains insertion order, hence does not maintains any doubly linked list.

Most salient feature of `LinkedHashMap` is that it maintains insertion order of key-value pairs. `LinkedHashMap` uses doubly Linked List for doing so.

Entry of `LinkedHashMap` looks like this:

```
  static class Entry<K, V> {
     K key;
     V value;
     Entry<K,V> next;
     Entry<K,V> before, after;        //For maintaining insertion order    
     public Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K,V> next){
         this.key = key;
         this.value = value;
         this.next = next;
     }
  }
```

By using before and after -  we keep track of newly added entry in `LinkedHashMap`, which helps us in maintaining insertion order.

Before refer to previous entry and
after refers to next entry in `LinkedHashMap`.

For diagrams and step by step explanation please refer http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/02/linkedhashmap-custom-implementation.html

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap inherits HashMap, that means it uses existing implementation of HashMap to store key and values in a Node (Entry Object). Other than this it stores a separate doubly linked list implementation to maintain the insertion order in which keys have been entered.

It looks like this :

header node <---> node 1 <---> node 2 <---> node 3 <----> node 4 <---> header node.

So extra overload is maintaining insertion and deletion in this doubly linked list.
Benefit is : Iteration order is guaranteed to be insertion order, which is not in HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

- Re-sizing is supposed to be faster as it iterates through its
  double-linked list to transfer the contents into a new table array.
- containsValue() is Overridden to take advantage of the faster
  iterator.
- LinkedHashMap can also be used to create a LRU cache. A special
  LinkedHashMap(capacity, loadFactor, accessOrderBoolean) constructor
  is provided to create a linked hash map whose order of iteration is
  the order in which its entries were last accessed, from
  least-recently accessed to most-recently. In this case, merely
  querying the map with get() is a structural modification.