# How to avoid items being re-ordered when put into java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm creating a new Map and pushing strings into it (no big deal) -but I've noticed that the strings are being re-ordered as the map grows. Is it possible to stop this re-ordering that occurs so the items in the map retain the order the were put in with?

```
Map<String,String> x = new HashMap<String, String>();
x.put("a","b");
x.put("a","c");
x.put("a","d");

x.put("1","2");
x.put("1","3");
x.put("1","4");

//this shows them out of order sadly...
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : x.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("IN THIS ORDER ... " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: If it's not sorted, it can't be a hashmap, really...

Comment: @tdammers - huh? Could you please explain that?

Comment: If it sorted its not a hash map would be more accurate.  A hash map places entries is a random pattern.  LinkedHashMap hides this by also remembering either the order you added them or the order they were last used. However they will still be placed in a random order in its underlying store.

Comment: What I mean is that the hashmap storage algorithm sorts entries by their hash to allow for O(log n) hash lookup (or rather, the sorting happens as a side effect of the way a hashmap stores its entries). Sorting by hash is not a random pattern, even though it may look like one due to the arbitrary nature of hash values.

Comment: @tdammers Probably a typo there -- Hashmaps strive for **O(1)** lookup on average; _treemaps_ strive for O(log n) lookup.

Comment: @Ray Toal: point taken - although the argument as it is stands.

Comment: @tdammers yes your argument is definitely spot on.  I was just nitpicking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you care about order, you can use a [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html). The actual class which implements the interface (at least for most scenarios) is a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Alternatively, [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) also maintains its order, while still utilizing a hashtable-based container.

Comment: Note that adding '7' to a search for the JavaDoc of a class will usually result in a link that points directly to the *latest* docs.

Answer (score 17):

You can keep it with `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 9):

A HashMap in java is not sorted http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html.  If you want predictable iteration order use a LinkedHashMap instead: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Heres a good discussion on the difference: [How is the implementation of LinkedHashMap different from HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020601/how-is-the-implementation-of-linkedhashmap-different-from-hashmap)

Comment: Note that adding '7' to a search for the JavaDoc of a class will usually result in a link that points directly to the *latest* docs.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers are correct in that you should use an implementation of Map that maintains ordering. LinkedHashMap and SortedMap each do these things.

However, the takeaway point is that not all collections maintain order and if order is important to you, you should choose the appropriate implementation. Generic HashMaps do not maintain order, do not claim to do so and cannot be set to do so.