# Parse many paths in the file tree object. Is there an efficient algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, graph, filetree

My code requires creation the file tree of the many file paths as

```
dir1/file1
dir1/dir2/file2
dir1/dir2/file3
```

FileTree object visualization example:

```
dir1
|_file1
|_dir2
  |_file2
  |_file3
```

This tree is used for torrent content files visualization in graphical form. It's also used for dynamically show files progress.
In a small number subfolders and files it works effectively, but if paths > 10,000 it takes a lot of memory and time (> 4 seconds and 50 MB RAM).

Is there an efficient algorithm for making such a graph? Most critical for me is the graph make speed. 
An example of algorithm implementation can be written in any language, it doesn't matter for me :-)
Thanks in advance.

My Java code for this purpose:

```
FileTree root = new FileTree(FileTree.ROOT, File.Type.DIR);
FileTree parentTree;

for (String pathToFile : paths) {
    parentTree = root;
    String[] nodes = FileIOUtils.parsePath(pathToFile); /*String.split(File.separator)*/

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            /* The last leaf item is a file */
        if (i == (nodes.length - 1)) {
            parentTree.addChild(new FileTree(nodes[i],
                File.Type.FILE, parentTree));
        } else {
            parentTree.addChild(new FileTree(nodes[i], FileNode.Type.DIR, parentTree));
        }

        FileTree nextParent = parentTree.getChild(nodes[i]);
            /* Skipping leaf nodes */
        if (nextParent != null && !nextParent.isFile()) {
            parentTree = nextParent;
        }
    }
}
```

FileTree class:

```
public class FileTree {
    public static final String ROOT = "/";
    /* The name for pointer to the parent node */
    public static final String PARENT_DIR = "..";

    protected String name;
    protected boolean isLeaf;
    protected FileTree parent;
    protected Map<String, FileTree> children = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public FileTree(String name, int type, FileTree parent) {
        this(name, type, parent);
    }

    public FileTree(String name, int type)
    {
        this(name, type, null);
    }

    public FileTree(String name, int type, FileTree parent)
    {
        this.name = name;
        isLeaf = (type == File.Type.FILE);
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public synchronized void addChild(FileTree node)
    {
        if (!children.containsKey(node.getName())) {
            children.put(node.getName(), node);
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(String name)
    {
        return children.containsKey(name);
    }

    public F getChild(String name)
    {
        return children.get(name);
    }

    public Collection<FileTree> getChildren()
    {
        return children.values();
    }

    public Set<String> getChildrenName()
    {
        return children.keySet();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

It was possible to achieve the speed of creating tree of 1000 subfolders an average of 0.5-1 second (early 30 second).

```
    FileTree root = new BencodeFileTree(FileTree.ROOT, 0L, File.Type.DIR);
    FileTree parentTree = root;
    /* It allows reduce the number of iterations on the paths with equal beginnings */
    String prevPath = "";
    /* Sort reduces the returns number to root */
    Collections.sort(files);

    for (String file : files) {
        String path;
        /*
         * Compare previous path with new path.
         * Example:
         * prev = dir1/dir2/
         * cur  = dir1/dir2/file1
         *        |________|
         *          equal
         *
         * prev = dir1/dir2/
         * cur  = dir3/file2
         *        |________|
         *         not equal
         */
        if (!prevPath.isEmpty() &&
                file.regionMatches(true, 0, prevPath, 0, prevPath.length())) {
            /*
             * Beginning paths are equal, remove previous path from the new path.
             * Example:
             * prev = dir1/dir2/
             * cur  = dir1/dir2/file1
             * new  = file1
             */
            path = file.substring(prevPath.length());
        } else {
            /* Beginning paths are not equal, return to root */
            path = file;
            parentTree = root;
        }

        String[] nodes = FileIOUtils.parsePath(path);
        /*
         * Remove last node (file) from previous path.
         * Example:
         * cur = dir1/dir2/file1
         * new = dir1/dir2/
         */
        prevPath = file.substring(0, file.length() - nodes[nodes.length - 1].length());

        /* Iterates path nodes */
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (!parentTree.contains(nodes[i])) {
                /* The last leaf item is a file */
                parentTree.addChild(makeObject(nodes[i], parentTree,
                                i == (nodes.length - 1)));
            }

            FileTree nextParent = parentTree.getChild(nodes[i]);
            /* Skipping leaf nodes */
            if (!nextParent.isFile()) {
                parentTree = nextParent;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain how it is going to be used. Different usage scenarios can be optimized in different way.

Comment: This tree is used for torrent content files visualization in graphical form. It's also used for dynamically show files progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic algorithm looks good to me, but you are creating a lot of unnecessary `FileTree` objects when you call `addChild` that will be immediately thrown away in the (common) case they already exist. You could try passing in the parameters to the constructor and only construct the object if it needs to be inserted:

```
public synchronized void addChild(String name, int type, FileTree parent)
{
    if (!children.containsKey(name)) {
        children.put(name, new FileTree(name, type, parent));
    }
}
```

and:

```
if (i == (nodes.length - 1)) {
     parentTree.addChild(nodes[i], File.Type.FILE, parentTree);
} else {
     parentTree.addChild(nodes[i], FileNode.Type.DIR, parentTree);
}
```

It might not be necessary to pass in `parentTree`: you can just construct it with `this`.

Another optimization could be to maintain the array of String objects (and associated FileTree nodes) from the previous path that you processed, and scan along until you find an entry that is different to the previous one before adding children.

Comment: Thank you. I remove child check exist from FileTree: 
`if (parentTree.contains(nodes[i])) { ... } `.
I use HashMap to store children (key: file name, value: FileTree), thus I can verify child existence in a tree, so I don't quite understand what you mean "array of String objects (and associated FileTree nodes".
I also create a tree in a separate class with static method, where I give paths list.

Comment: I mean in your for loop where you process `String nodes[]` you could also keep track of a `String prevNodes[]` and compare strings. So if you had `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1` and then `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir6/file1`, you could start processing at dir6, instead of dir1. It might be too complicated for little benefit however. P.S. did the change you already made make any difference to the speed?

Comment: I did something similar to your option, in consideration the possible repetition of names in the tree. For trees with a large number of subfolders speed is improved at about 2-2.5 times (for example, tree with 1000 subfolder and in each folder 10 files - make tree time 2.5 seconds (5 seconds earlier). Here is my code (it's yet crude, made it for check) [http://pastebin.com/PwQ3sprD](http://pastebin.com/PwQ3sprD)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to replace `LinkedHashMap` with `HashMap` because first one consumes more memory. The main difference is that `HashMap` does not guaranty order of iteration over entries. But you could order children in GUI (probably you have some ordering setting anyway). Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020601/how-is-the-implementation-of-linkedhashmap-different-from-hashmap) for some references.

---

Another suggestion would be to return actual child node from method `addChild`

```
public synchronized FileTree addChild(FileTree node) {
    return children.putIfAbsent(node.getName(), node);
}
```

Then inside loop there is no need to call `get` on map again

```
FileTree nextParent = parentTree.addChild(...
```

---

And there is condition that looks unnecessary

```
if (nextParent != null && !nextParent.isFile()) {
    parentTree = nextParent;
}
```

Looks like there will be no iteration in loop if current child is a file. So it could be safely replaced with

```
parentTree = parentTree.addChild(...
```

---

After suggestions loop body would look like

```
for(...) {
    int type = if (i == (nodes.length - 1)) ? File.Type.FILE : FileNode.Type.DIR;
    parentTree = parentTree.addChild(new FileTree(nodes[i], type, parentTree);
}
```